# How to make one process to frequently check for one of the column value in database and react accordingly in java

Tags: java

I'm new to java. I'm trying to Load some csv's to Postgres using java.
My requirement is as following:-

I'm transferring zip file from local server via sftp to the server where I would like to run loading.jar.
Usually, once all the csv's zipped and transferred to the server we can run loading.jar to unzip and load data to postgres. But, I'm looking at, what if we run loading.jar first at the reomte server and sftp.jar at local server later and loading.jar must frequently check for the status as 'RECEIVED' in one of the driving table which will be updated as soon as the file is transferred successfully by the sftp.jar.

How can we achieve this?? How to build a loading.jar which will frequently check for status in one of the table and pick it up for loading?? Sample code can help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are many ways in which you can achieve that. Starting from `Thread.sleep` and going thru all libraries for scheduling to some Spring annotation based solution. You should ask more specific question.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try with Thread.sleep

Comment: Downloading data per SFTP, loading data to database, watching database table for new records. These are all use cases for an integration framework like [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org). You should take a look at this.